# Can't install Ubuntu 15.10 from USB - Windows Dualboot

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 15.10, live-usb

I've installed Ubuntu on several other machines but cant get it to run on my new build. 
I'v created a bootable USB drive using the official 15.10 iso from ubuntu using pendrive linux. Secure boot is disabled, fast boot is disabled and IOMMU is enabled. When booting from USB the I get the list where I select "Install Ubuntu." The Ubuntu Logo screen appears and then I get this error screen:

[image: error screen]

Here is my BIOS Info:

[image: BIOS info]

System info:

- Gigabyte GA 970 Gaming
- AMD FX 8320
- GTX 960 4gb SSC
- 16gb Crucial Ram
- Kingston 120gm SSD (Reserved for Linux install)
- M2 SSD (Running Windows OS)
- WD 1TB HDD (Windows Storage)

Any ideas on how to get past this?

Comment: Could this be related to my graphics driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had some issues with a usb and 15.10 too. I solved it by going old-school, burn the iso to a dvd and installed it that way. Maybe this works for you too, if not.... Well, at least you tried.

Comment: Tried it with several different LTS .iso files... Still achieved the same result.

Comment: Was able to install 15.10 using a DVD. Unfortunately, now I can't access the internet through ethernet or wifi...

Answer (score 0):

You are facing an NVIDIA graphics related issue ... and that is what you have to do :

Step 1 : Ubuntu system installation

Boot from the installation media and select Try Ubuntu without installing.
Press the <kbd>E</kbd> key - add `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the `linux` line.
Set a <kbd>Space</kbd> between the last character in the `linux` line and `nouveau.modeset=0`.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu Live desktop and now install Ubuntu.

Step 2 : NVIDIA drivers installation

When finished reboot the system and now select the Ubuntu menu entry.
Press the <kbd>E</kbd> key - add `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the `linux` line.
Set a <kbd>Space</kbd> between the last character in the `linux` line and `nouveau.modeset=0`.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system and install the NVIDIA drivers.

Reboot the Ubuntu system ... now you don't have to add the parameter any more.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a shot in the morning. I had a feeling it was related to my graphics card...

Comment: Followed the above instructions and added nouveau.modeset=0 to the end of the linux line. I hit F10 and get the Ubuntu screen. Next I get the top 3 lines from the error screen in my original post followed by the BusyBox line. The three "nouveau" lines no longer appear.

Comment: @cberu001 : Replace nouveau.modeset=0  with nomodeset and try it again. :)

Comment: no luck.  Do i add nomodeset to the very end of the line, or do I replace quiet splash as shown in [My Computer Boots to Black Screen] (http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)     Here is what my linux line looks like:  linux          /casper/vmlinuz.efi file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash --

Comment: @cberu001 Please check whether you can disable the NVIDIA adapter in BIOS ... don't attach an external monitor during the installation process. After having installed the drivers re-enable the adapter or select switchable graphics mode. As every machine and every BIOS is different, unfortunately I cannot give you more specific instructions. :)

Comment: How do you complete the install without a monitor?